# jQuery - RCarousel slideshow - Dynamic width?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slideshow, grid-layout

Is it possible to make rcarousel work with a liquid layout / adaptive UI ?

It only seems to work with a fixed width and height... it doesn't run if I use percentages like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   jQuery(function($) {
      $( "#carousel" ).rcarousel( {width: 100%, height: 100%, visible:1, step:1});
   });
</script>
```

The only time the dimensions are specified is in the code above, so without percentages how could it handle the resize event (e.g. iPad going from landscape to portrait)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The Window.bind('resize', function ...   could get me started but it just doesn't seem like the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just made my own carousel that will work in an adaptive UI (there really is no need for rCarousel if you're familiar with the jQueryUI library).